# Pivot Table: group by date and show the date for each row listed

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table

I'm able to group by date and then all the rows are, as expected, grouped by date.  What I'd like is that for every row on which data is listed, it also shows the date associated with that entry - is that possible?  I can't seem to figure out how to accomplish this.

So, for example, I have a bunch of tax entries in a table and I want to group them by year in a pivot table (using tabular view) and when I expand a particular year I can see all the entries, but I also want to see the exact date for each entry.  So far I can't figure out how to group by date yet also show the full date entry either...

Thanks!
Mike

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exaclty how your data is organized, but say it is like that:

[image]

We can add a Pivot Table to generate something like that:

[image]

That is close to what you are asking: date grouped by year, and the exact date for a particular entry.
To do that, we add the Date in the Rows and Values fields. We also add the Balance in the Rows field. By doing that, you can group the dates on the rows by year. To show the exact date for a particular entry, you also add the Date on the Values field. You must change the Format of this field to a Date format to show the actual date not the value used on Excel to store the date.

[image]

Comment: So that is really close!  It does force me to put the date at the very right side of the pivot table which isn't really ideal.  What I'd really like is to have the date just to the right of the grouped date column as that would make the information flow better.  Do you think there's any way to move it around?

Comment: I did some more searching and ended up finding this - which kinda goes on to say that I can't do what I'm wanting to do:

https://www.excelcampus.com/pivot-tables/grouped-date-field-formatting/